# Does an .htaccess redirect to a different folder activate the second .htaccess within?

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, redirect

On my apache site, I have the following redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1
```

which redirects from the root directory, to the "Web" directory.

Will this also run through the .htaccess of the `/web/` directory too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. (Assuming `.htaccess` overrides have not been disabled for the subdirectory.)

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1
> ```

In fact, if the `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory contains mod_rewrite directives then you don't need the `RewriteCond` directive, since the mod_rewrite directives in the subdirectory will override the directives in the parent (by default) and thus prevent a rewrite loop.

Note that in the directive you posted you are missing an `L` flag, so processing will first continue through the rest of the current `.htaccess` file.

Minor point, this is strictly a "rewrite", not a "redirect". Although the Apache docs do refer to "internal redirects". A "redirect" is more commonly used to refer to *external* 3xx redirects.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a **lot**!